# Problem with running Nextjs app. Stopped immediately after started

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, server-error

I have install Nextjs app. But could not started the app. Its stopped immediately. My terminal shows below like -

```
PS D:\Nextjs\MyApp> npm run dev

> dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000

PS D:\Nextjs\MyApp>
```

I have checked node version or folder structure. Its OK. My system is 32 bit, windows 10.

I have uninstall node then again install. Manually setup nextjs. Tried js and ts separately. But nothing work. In my machine I have successfully build MERN or Nest app.

Answer (score 2):

I apparently had the same issue almost at the same time. I was trying to `npm run dev` a NextJS app from scratch using `npx create-next-app`.

For me when I upgraded the node version it started working again. I was running a `14.x.x` node version and NextJS `13.2.3` when the issue occurred to me.

Now I am running node `18.14.2 LTS` and NextJS `13.2.3` and the command `npm run dev` is running as expected.

Comment: node version - v18.14.2 and nextjs version -13.2.4. Problem still remain.

Answer (score 1):

Downgraded from Nodejs `18.15.0` to `18.14.2` and it works fine now.

Comment: node version - v18.14.2 and nextjs version -13.2.4. Problem still remain.

Comment: try nextjs versions 13.2.3, thats what works for me

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue on my side as well, later on realizing that I hade Node 32bit installed instead of 64bit.

You can check by running `node -p "process.arch"` and if it is showing 32bit uninstall Node and install from a 64 bit installer (I installed node-v18.15.0-x64.msi) and I was able to run `npm run dev` from then on.